# Передача переменной модулю

Tags: python

Есть программа для взаимодействия с 3d-принтером. Я прикрутил к ней модуль, который позволяет работать с текстовым дисплеем, тактовый кнопками и флешкой. Запускается программа, потом автоматически стартует модуль, который считывает файлы с флешки и выводит их на дисплей в виде списка. Список листается тактовыми кнопками и потом имя выбранного файла в переменной передаётся в основную программу из модуля. Программа печатает этот файл и нужно выводить процент печати на дисплей. Для отображния процесса печати в % в программе существует отдельная переменная. Но если я снова вызову модуль, работа основной программы приостановится, пока модуль снова не закроется. Как в режиме реального времени без костылей передавать в модуль значение переменной?

На данный момент момент я передаю имя файла так:
Сейчас у меня все выглядит так:
Программа 1:

```
...
import program
...
filename=program.main()
...
```

Программа 2:

```
...
global fname
fname="file_name"
return fname  
...
```

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Что вы понимаете под "вызвать модуль"? Вы можете вызвать функцию, но загрузить/импортировать модуль, или выполнить модуль как скрипт (`__name__=='__main__`). Возможно вы пытаетесь организовать программу, чтобы она могла делать несколько вещей одновременно—для сетевого кода и GUI кода часто используют кооперативную многозадачность—яркий пример JavaScript  (все события в одном потоке происходят, чередуясь) и только избранные вещи исполняются в фоновом пуле потоков/процессов (которые в принципе параллельно могут работать).